# How to fix the Ubuntu Server TTY cannot fullscreen anymore after upgraded in VMwar Player?

Tags: ubuntu

Here my condition:

- The system is **Windows7 64bit**.
- VMware Player has been upgraded to **6.0.3 build-1895310**.
- VMware Tools is **VMWareTools-9.6.2-1688356**
- The guest system is **Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS amd64** (**No** X-windows)

I've set the screen resolution in `/etc/default/grub` to

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280X1024
```

And it works fine until the system upgraded yesterday.

Details can be found as below:
[image: grub]

How can I fix that? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try to reinstall vmware tools

Comment: Yes, It has been reinstalled about 10 times or so....And, for verifying my assumption. I've installed a new guest just now. The TTY still cannot be set as full-screen after upgraded first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the way! By executing:

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ reboot
```

And it will be fixed.

### Reason

```
$ man update-grub
....
DESCRIPTION
    update-grub is a stub for running grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg to generate a grub2 config file.
....
```

My assumption is: after executed `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`. The linux shell or kernel was upgraded. The previous version of **grub.cfg** has been replaced after upgraded.

The **new** `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has be generated by manual even if the grub config file (/etc/default/grub) wasn't changed.

Here the different between before and after manually execute and reboot
[image]

**By the way, there are nothing related with VMware Player version or even VMwareTools**. It'll work no matter VMwareTools installed or not.